# How to properly map over array of url and get data into state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

In this code block I am mapping over an array of Spotify urls, getting there data, and trying to push them into state. As of right now this code returns an array of promises and does not await the actual data. This doesn't make sense to me as I am awaiting the data from the axios call.

```
const fetchSpotifyData = async () => {
    const allTracks = data.map(async (d) => {
      let track = {
        album: "",
        image: "",
        artist: "",
        trackName: "",
        externalUrl: "",
      };
      const incomingTrack = await axios.get(
        `https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/${d.uri}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${spotifyToken}`,
          },
        }
      );
      console.log(incomingTrack) // the data is here and is correct
      track.album = incomingTrack.data.album.name;
      track.image = incomingTrack.data.album.images[0].url;
      track.artist = incomingTrack.data.artists[0].name;
      track.trackName = incomingTrack.data.name;
      track.externalUrl = incomingTrack.data.external_urls.spotify;
      console.log(track) // this shows the correct track data
      return track;
    });
        console.log(allTracks)// Array [ Promise {
  //  "_U": 0,
   // "_V": 0,
  //  "_W": null,
  //  "_X": null,
 // },
 // ]

  return allTracks;
  };
```

Comment: If you pass an `async` callback to any of the looping array methods like `forEach`, `map` e.t.c. then you have to `Promise.all` the resultant array. The methods themselves will not `await` in between loops. Alternatively you can use a `for...of` loop to handle each Promise individually.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be the nature of the function, you are awaiting on a array of promises and the not promise itself.

An alternative and mostly suggested solutions is to simply return the promise from map. This way you'll have an array of promises.

From there, you can use `Promise.all` to resolve those promises. Promise.all receives an array of promises, or you can also use `Promise.allSettled`.

Read more about `Promise.all`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
const fetchSpotifyData = async () => {
    const allTracks = data.map((d) => {

      return axios.get(
        `https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/${d.uri}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${spotifyToken}`,
          },
        }
      );

    });
  return allTracks;
  };
let track = {
  album: "",
  image: "",
  artist: "",
  trackName: "",
  externalUrl: "",
};

Promise.all(fetchSpotifyData()).then((data) => {
  // do you operations
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a simplified version of your code, you will see that what you need is [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

According to the docs:

> The Promise.all() method takes an **iterable** of promises as an input, and **returns a single Promise** that **resolves to an array of the results** of the input promises.

In your case, an iterable is an array. And since it returns a promise with your results, you need to *await* it as well.

Below I created a snippet so that you better understand what is happening. Note that I stubbed out the Spotify axios API call with my own promise, but the inputs and outputs should be similar enough:

```js
const spotifyStubPromise = (songId) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve([
  {album: "Programming is Great"},
  {album: "But Code Is Hard"},
][songId]));

data = [{id: 0}, {id: 1}];

const fetchSpotifyData = async () => {
  const allTracks = data.map(async (song) => {
    let track = {
      album: "",
    };
    const incomingTrack = await spotifyStubPromise(song.id);
    console.log("Incoming track -> ", incomingTrack) // the data is here and is correct
    track.album = incomingTrack.album;
    console.log("Processed track -> ", track) // this shows the correct track data
    return track;
  });
  console.log("all tracks (array of Promises) -> ", allTracks);
  
  
  
  const allTracksSync = await Promise.all(allTracks); // waits for all the promises to finish
  console.log("all tracks (array of data) -> ", allTracksSync);
  return allTracks;
};

fetchSpotifyData();
```